# Re-write rule for angular 2 app and web service on same server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, angular, ngroute

I need to correct the below re-writes rule below so that any url called will get directed to / or index.html but if the url is for the web service (/ws/controller/function) then i want it to direct to /ws/index.php

For my angular 2 in the html i have

```
<base href="/">
```

And the url is format xxx/yyy/ not #/xx/yy

my .htaccess is

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /ws/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ws/index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
</ifModule>

<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On 
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]

</ifModule>
```

It works fine as it is but when the user reloads the page on any other than the root the app falls over.

Thanks

Comment: Why have you got one URL for webservice and another for your app ?

Comment: Because my single page web app and the web service sit on the same server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would help:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ws/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(ws/.*)$ ws/index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]

</ifModule>
```